# For loop Type Error: 'Dictionary' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, google-earth-engine

I am trying to build a for loop in Python which exports images from Google Earth Engine into my Google Drive. The bounding box coordinates for each image are taken from a data frame called DHS.

I have successfully exported a single image using the following code:

```
landsat = ee.Image('ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3')

geometry = [[DHS.loc[1,'lon.min'], DHS.loc[1,'lat.min']], 
            [DHS.loc[1,'lon.min'], DHS.loc[1,'lat.max']],
            [DHS.loc[1,'lon.max'], DHS.loc[1,'lat.max']],
            [DHS.loc[1,'lon.max'], DHS.loc[1,'lat.min']]]

File_Name = str(DHS.loc[1,'Survey Year']) + "_" + str(DHS.loc[1,'Cluster Number'])

task_config = { 
    'folder': 'Earth Engine Data',
    'region': geometry
    }

task = ee.batch.Export.image(landsat, File_Name, task_config)

task.start()
```

However, when I try to put this code into a for-loop, I get the following error:

```
landsat = ee.Image('ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3')

for row in range(0,1):

    geometry = [[DHS.loc[row,'lon.min'], DHS.loc[row,'lat.min']],
                [DHS.loc[row,'lon.min'], DHS.loc[row,'lat.max']],
                [DHS.loc[row,'lon.max'], DHS.loc[row,'lat.max']],
                [DHS.loc[row,'lon.max'], DHS.loc[row,'lat.min']]]

    File_Name = str(DHS.loc[row,'Survey Year']) + "_" + str(DHS.loc[row,'Cluster Number'])

    task_config = {
        'folder': 'Earth Engine Data',
        'region': geometry
        }

    task = ee.batch.Export.image(landsat, File_Name, task_config)

    task.start()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-164162d7da6c> in <module>
      1 landsat = ee.Image('ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3')
      2 
----> 3 for row in range(0,1):
      4 
      5     geometry = [[DHS.loc[row,'lon.min'], DHS.loc[row,'lat.min']],

TypeError: 'Dictionary' object is not callable
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have replaced the built-in `range` with a dictionary.

It must happen somewhere in a part of the code that you did not post.

You can easily reproduce this:

```
print(range) # <class 'range'>
range = {}
print(type(range)) # <class 'dict'>
for i in range(5): # TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
    pass
```

Next time, please post a stand-alone minimal, complete and verifiable example, that includes all the code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Mike, you are absolutely right, it was from a section of code I copied and pasted from a GitHub page and then forgot about. Thanks, I'll make sure to do that in the future!

Comment: @Misc584 If it answered your question don't forget to mark it as an answer. It tells other you no longer need an answer and it will give reputation to the person who helped solve your problem.